# Converting bits to decimal (integer) string is so slow

Tags: c++, performance, integer, number-systems

I am implementing myself a BigInteger class. It can natively handle very very big digits in very short time.

```
2 ^ 200000 == Time Elapsed : 12.343
Number of binary digits : 200001
```

The only problem is, when I do `std::cout << foo;`, I have to wait for very very long. Because my BigInteger class has to perform a **std::string** multiplication and a **std::string** increment on very single bit. As the number of bits increases, it might even take ages to finish.

```
Printing foo took 160.485 second(s) // It is so so long!!!
```

I have actually optimized my outputting algorithm to the best of my abilities. Some tricks include using reference, using array temp variables for fast caching. But for very very big numbers, it is still not fast enough.

Here is my code :

```
void BigInteger::doubleNumberString_1A63(std::string &string_input, std::string &string_tmp)
{
    int64_t i;
    int32_t t, t_1 = 0, t_2;

    string_tmp = "";

    char buffer[1024];
    int32_t n = 0;

    for(i = string_input.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        t = t_1 + (string_input[i] - '0') * 2;

        t_1 = t / 10;
        t_2 = t % 10;

        buffer[n++] = (char)('0' + t_2);
        if(n == sizeof(buffer)){string_tmp.append(buffer, n); n = 0;}
    }

    if(t_1 >= 1) buffer[n++] = (char)('0' + t_1);
    if(n) string_tmp.append(buffer, n);
}


void BigInteger::incrementNumberString_1A63(std::string &string_input, std::string &string_tmp, int32_t inc_val = 1)
{
    int64_t i;
    int32_t t, t_1 = 0, t_2;

    string_input = "";

    char buffer[1024];
    int32_t n = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < string_tmp.size(); i++)
    {
        t = t_1 + (string_tmp[i] - '0') + inc_val; 

        t_1 = t / 10;
        t_2 = t % 10;

        inc_val = 0;

        buffer[n++] = (char)('0' + t_2);
        if(n == sizeof(buffer)){string_input.append(buffer, n); n = 0;}
    }

    if(t_1 >= 1) buffer[n++] = (char)('0' + t_1);
    if(n) string_input.append(buffer, n);

    std::reverse(string_input.begin(), string_input.end());
}

void BigInteger::printRawBinaryToDecimal(std::ostream &os) const
{
    const BigInteger &num = (*this);

    int64_t i;
    int64_t num_sz = num.size();

    if(BIG_INTEGER_INTEGER_DIGIT_BASE_A8F23ABC == 2)
    {
        std::string buf_base10 = "0";
        std::string buf_basetmp;

        // num.operator[](i) // --> Access each bit
        for(i = num_sz - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            doubleNumberString_1A63(buf_base10, buf_basetmp);
            incrementNumberString_1A63(buf_base10, buf_basetmp, BigInteger::IntegerUnit::toDigit(num.operator[](i)));
        }

        os << buf_base10;
    }   
}


std::ostream &operator << (std::ostream &os, const BigInteger &num)
{
    num.printRawBinaryToDecimal(os); return os;
}
```

Here we go, for each bit, the BigInteger class has to call **doubleNumberString_1A63** and **incrementNumberString_1A63**, and it is the traditional method (and slow of course). Could anyone greatly improve it or suggest even a faster algorithm? I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Of course it is heavily optimized. How about you write a quick class definition for yourself, particularly paying attention to the operator [] which can either return 0 or 1. Of course, the container is a std::vector.

Comment: Posting at least the class definition - the implementation is 2503 lines long.

Comment: My BigInteger class stores its values in **real bits** (OR 32 bits per container element). The container element is an uint32_t.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to do arithmetic with strings, that is bound to be expensive.

Here is a naive algorithm to output a BigInteger in decimal:

```
std::stringstream output;
BigInteger num = the_number;
while(num != 0) {
    output << static_cast<int>(num%10);
    num = num/10;
}
std::string output_str = output.str();
std::reverse(output_str.begin(), output_str.end());
return output_str;
```

of course you need to implement the operators `%`, `/` and cast to `int` first.

This can also be easily improved by chunking to the maximal power of 10 holdable in an unsigned int or unsigned long.

However this naive algortithm still has quadratic time complexity in the length of the number. I am not sure whether there is a linear time algorithm. Another quadratic, but possibly faster algorithm is [Double dabble](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dabble).

[In the GMP documentation](https://gmplib.org/manual/Binary-to-Radix.html) there is a short explanation of a subquadratic algorithm. Maybe this can give you some directions. You may want to look at its source anyway as a reference of a mature BigInteger implementation.

I am also quite confused by your function names. What is `_1A63` supposed to mean? I doubt the end of the function name is the correct place for whatever it is. Is it representing the container element types? If so that should belong into a template parameter.

Comment: '_1A63' : Random postfix to make the functions sound unique. It says that the functions are probably reversed for private program implementation.

Comment: I will try your suggestion. If everything works out, I guarantee your answer will be accepted :)

Comment: @xersi Implementation methods are simply declared `private` in C++, so there is no way for others to use them. There is also no naming conflict, because the author of the class is the only one able to declare member functions. Even for derived types that is not a problem.

Comment: Help!! The Double dabble algorithm is not working!!

Comment: http://textuploader.com/daaxf

Comment: @xersi The code from wikipedia works as intended, only that you changed the number of bits represented by each element of `arr` to `sizeof(unsigned int)*8` (32 on my system) instead of 16. Read the comment at the top again to see what `arr` represents.

Comment: I do not really understand what you are saying, can you post the code that is guaranted to work (use some text-hosting website) without me having to worry too much about it? And why since the data that is being performed is unsigned int, why did the author choose 16 not 32 "nbits = 16 * n;" - **16** is actually the number of bits of an unsigned short perhaps?

Comment: @xersi With 32bit per array element and `arr = {0, 1, 0}` the number represented is 4294967296 and it is exactly the output I get. If I chance `bits_per_element` to `16` I get 65536 as output, which is also correct if every arr element represents 16bit. The value of `bits_per_element` is arbitary as long as `bits_per_element <= sizeof(unsigned int)*CHAR_BIT`. Note that the C++ standard only requires that `unsigned int` can hold numbers represented up to 16bit binaries. Thus 16 bit is safe, but 32 bit is not (but of course you could change `unsigned int` to `uint32_t` or `unsigned long`.

Comment: @xersi The size of integer types is not always the same. The compiler may choose different sizes depending on the platform. There is only a required minimal size defined in the C++ standard, see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types#Properties

Comment: Have you tried these?
arr = {0, 1, 0} // == 2^32
arr = {0, 0, 1} // == 2^64
I do not know whether or not you are right, but it is not working properly on my machine now. Of course unsigned int is 4 bytes (I am not taking about ancient compilers). **Can you show me the code that works so that I do not need to worry about it too much?**

Comment: `arr = {0, 0, 1} // == 2^64`, no, the first element of `arr` has the highest significance. It is good practise to adhere to the standard even if recent x86 desktop platforms usually have int as 32bit. Think of someone trying to compile your code for some small microcontroller. I am not here to write your code for you. You _should_ worry about your code. You should even implement the algorithm yourself instead of copying it from wikipedia. What is the point if you don't understand the code?

Comment: In other words, we probably have to reverse the order of the data array so that we can achieve the correct results?
Actually, my BigInteger also has to iterate though each bit from the end to the beginning to print each bit; is it a coincidence?

Comment: For your information, it is how my BigInteger stores data - Instead of arr = {1, 0, 0, 0, 0} (2^128), the order of my data is {0, 0, 0, 0, 1} (assuming uint128_t does exist)

Comment: @xersi The order you choose doesn't really matter. You just need to consider what order the algorithm expects and reverse it if necessary.

Comment: Well, the **Double Dabble** algorithm is a huge boost, but it still fails to satisfy me when I try my calculation on even bigger numbers. For example, **33333 ^ 33333** ends in 3.218 seconds (about 500818 bits), but it takes up to **126.313** second(s) just to print out this number.

Answer (score 0):

I am glad I am able to solve this problem thanks to **Eichhörnchen**.
Everything works out, and as a plus, I even managed to increase my raw calculation performance up to **36.96%**!!

Before :

- 2 ^ 200000 == Time Elapsed : 12.343
- Number of binary digits : 200001
- Printing foo took 160.485 second(s)

After :

- 2 ^ 200000 == Time Elapsed : **7.781**
- Number of binary digit : 200001
- Printing foo took **20.672** second(s)

That is at least **8x** faster. Even though it is not that extremely impressive, I can now believe that implementing a BigInteger is not that very challenging and very difficult anymore. Sure it may be great if there is an even more impressive algorithm out there, I will get to discover it soon if there's any.